# How to Update with a Self join?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgres table, containing election results like this:

```
CREATE TABLE results
(
  seats character varying(255),
  candidate character varying(255),
  party character varying(255),
  votes numeric(10,0)
  status character varying(2)
)
```

I can get the names of the winners using the following query:

```
select r.seats, r.candidate, r.votes
FROM results r
join(
select seats as s, max(votes) as mv
FROM results
group by seats) as a
on r.seats=a.s AND r.votes=a.mv;
```

Now I wish to set the `status` column of all these winner to be equal to 'W', but I can't manage to write a SQL query to do this.

I've tried this query, but it sets the `status` for all rows to be 'W':

```
update results set status='W'
FROM results r
join(
select seats as s, max(votes) as mv
FROM results
group by seats) as a
on r.seats=a.s AND r.votes=a.mv;
```

How do I write an `Update..From` query to update only those rows containing the 'winners' I get by the first query?

Comment: `UPDATE ... FROM` is what you want.

Comment: I tried that, but it sets `status` in all the rows to 'w'; Can you give me a query which will set status only for these 'winners'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update results as r set
    status = 'W'
from (
    select t.seats, max(t.votes) as max_votes
    from results as t
    group by t.seats
) as a
where a.seats = r.seats and a.max_votes = r.votes;
```

Comment: I get the following error: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "on"`